how to navigate between similar texts in visual studio
when selecting some text in visual studio similar texts will be highlighted as shown in the picture.

I would like to know if there a keyboard shortcut that can move selection next or previous to the similar text?

I have quick find bound to ctrl+f which will quickly allow me to search the current document. By default the search term is the currently selected text and I can then use F3 and shift+F3 to navigate between matches. Your VS config may be different though.
